# How to decide which NoSQL technology to use?

Tags: mongodb, neo4j, hbase, graph-databases, nosql

What is the pros and cons of MongoDB (document-based), HBase (column-based) and Neo4j (objects graph)?

I'm particularly interested to know some of the typical use cases for each one.

[What are good examples of problems that graphs can solve better than the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703999/what-are-some-examples-of-problems-that-are-best-solved-with-graphs)

Maybe any Slideshare or Scribd worthy presentation?

Comment: First you need to know what kind of data you will have.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**MongoDB**

*Scalability:* Highly available and consistent but sucks at relations and many distributed writes. It's primary benefit is storing and indexing schemaless documents. Document size is capped at 4mb and indexing only makes sense for limited depth. See http://www.paperplanes.de/2010/2/25/notes_on_mongodb.html

*Best suited for:* Tree structures with limited depth

*Use Cases:* Diverse Type Hierarchies, Biological Systematics, Library Catalogs

**Neo4j**

*Scalability:* Highly available but not distributed. Powerful traversal framework for high-speed traversals in the node space. Limited to graphs around several billion nodes/relationships. See http://highscalability.com/neo4j-graph-database-kicks-buttox

*Best suited for:* Deep graphs with unlimited depth and cyclical, weighted connections

*Use Cases:* Social Networks, Topological analysis, Semantic Web Data, Inferencing

**HBase**

*Scalability:* Reliable, consistent storage in the petabytes and beyond. Supports very large numbers of objects with a limited set of sparse attributes. Works in tandem with Hadoop for large data processing jobs. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-hbase/index.html

*Best suited for:* directed, acyclic graphs

*Use Cases:* Log analysis, Semantic Web Data, Machine Learning

Comment: How HBase is suitable for Acyclic graphs? It isn't a graph database such Neo4J

Comment: How would you put it Chiron?

Comment: This answer is dated. For a great comparison that's kept up to date please check out http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis 

Kudos to Eddie Wong for pointing it out in his answer below

Answer (score 4):

I know this might seem like an odd place to point to but, Heroku has recently gone nuts with their noSQL offerings and have an OK overview of many of the current projects.  It is in no way a Slideshare press but it will help you start the comparison process:

http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2010/7/20/nosql/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=EmailBlast&utm_content=619506254&utm_campaign=HerokuSeptemberNewsletter-VersionB&utm_term=NoSQLHerokuandYou

Answer (score 4):

Checkout this for at glance comparison of NoSQL dbs:

http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis

Comment: That is actually a great resource that keeps up to date with new products. Too bad I can't upvote this answer again.

Answer (score 1):

**MongoDB:**

MongoDB is document database unlike Relational database. The document stores semi structured data like JSON object ( schema free)

***Key features:***

1. Schema can change over evolution of application
2. Full indexing
3. Load balancing  & Data sharding
4. Data replication
5. Consistency & Partitioning in CAP theory ( Consistency-Availability-Partitioning)

***When to use:***

1. Real time analytics
2. High speed logging
3. Semi structured data management

***When not to use:***

1. Highly transactional applications with strong ACID properties ( Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation & Durability). RDBMS is preferred in this use case.
2. Operating on data sets involving relations - foreign keys etc

**HBASE:**

HBase is an open source, non-relational, distributed column family database

***Key features:***

1. It provides a fault-tolerant way of ***storing large quantities of sparse data*** (small amounts of information caught within a large collection of empty or unimportant data, such as finding the 50 largest items in a group of 2 billion records, or finding the non-zero items representing less than 0.1% of a huge collection)
2. Supports variable schema where each row is different
3. Can serve as the input and output for MapReduce job
4. Compression, in-memory operation, and Bloom filters on a per-column (A data structure designed to tell you, rapidly and memory-efficiently, whether an element is present in a set)
   5.Achieve CP on CAP

***When to use HBase:***

1. If you’re loading data by key, searching data by key (or range), serving data by key, querying data by key
2. Storing data by row that doesn’t conform well to a schema (variable schema)

***When not to use HBase:***

1. For relational analytics
2. Full table scans
3. Data to be aggregated, analyzed by rows instead of columns

**Neo4j:**

Neo4j is graph database using Property Graph Data Model (Data is stored as a graph and nodes & relationships with properties)

***Key features:***

1. Supports full ACID(Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation and Durability) rules
2. Supports Indexes by using Apache Lucence
3. Schema free, bottom-up data model design
4. High scalability has been achieved due to compact storage and memory caching available for graphs

***When to use:***

1. Master data management
2. Network and IT Operations
3. Real time recommendations
4. Fraud detection
5. Social network (like facebook)

***When not to use:***

1. Bulk queries/Scans
2. If your application requires Partitioning & Sharding of data

Have a look at comparison of various NoSQL technologies in this [article](http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis)

Sources:

Wiki, [Slide share](http://www.slideshare.net/EdurekaIN/no-sql-databases-35591065), [Cloudera](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2011/04/hbase-dos-and-donts/),[Tutorials Point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/neo4j/neo4j_features_advantages.htm),[Neo4j](http://neo4j.com/use-cases/)

Answer (score 0):

You could also evaluate a **Multi-Model** DBMS, as the second generation of NoSQL product. With a Multi-Model you don't have all the compromises on choosing just one model, but rather more than one model.

The first multi-model NoSQL is [OrientDB](http://www.orientechnologies.com/why-orientdb/).

Answer (score -1):

Pretty decent article here on MongoDB and NoRM (.net extensions for MongoDB)
http://lukencode.com/2010/07/09/getting-started-with-mongodb-and-norm/